# How can I make a SAS dataset read only within a SAS program?

Tags: sas

How can I set a sas data table (`sas7bdat`) to read-only within a SAS Program? — the table must remain readonly even between sessions, especially if another user registers the library and attempts to write to the dataset. Once these tables have been created I do not wish to ever edit them - they are "point-in-time" reference tables that others and myself may rely on. Being able to lock dow the tables and guarantee that they tables have not been accidentally changed would save a lot of data verification each time these tables are used.

I wish to protect only from dangerous code that may accidentally alter the table, such as :

```
PROC SORT 
    DATA = JUSTIN.myreadonlytable;
    BY 
        ref
        start_date;
RUN;
```

I do not mind if someone can alter a read-only flag in the filesystem but I would like that the default behaviour in SAS is to error when an attempt to write to the table occurs.

Comment: To make your question clearer, you might change the initial sentence to make it clear you are talking about creating a dataset that others do not modify, not about how to change your own programs to not modify datasets.

Comment: I've clarified it now. I'll try the password solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to prevent people from accidentally writing to the dataset, then you want to assign an `alter` password.

```
data test(alter="def");
 set sashelp.class;
run;
```

That prevents altering (writing to, replacing, deleting) the dataset without supplying the password in the same fashion (or typing the password in a popup window).

Comment: Note the `PWREQ=` option controls the dialog box appearing or not appearing, but seems to apply to the later uses, not the initial creation.

Answer (score 2):

Add ACCESS=READONLY on the libname is one option. Details here:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000214133.htm

Comment: It seems that this would not work if someone else registered the library in their session without the `ACCESS=READONLY` command.

Comment: I think your question is probably not entirely clear.